# libSVM accuracy differs from grid search

Tags: svm, libsvm

I am working on a dataset with 2 classes and i'm trying different kernels and parameters with libSVM. My problem is that the accuracy values that i get from grid search are very different from the ones that i take training and predicting on the same dataset.

For example, in the grid search with linear kernel, one of the best values i get is:

```
log2c=1 log2g=1 rate=78.9531
```

that correctly is the same that i get running the training with 5-fold:

```
[...]
optimization finished, #iter = 13642
nu = 0.000549
obj = -4.003812, rho = -1.539489
nSV = 1681, nBSV = 2
Total nSV = 1681
Cross Validation Accuracy = 78.9531%
```

but if i train without n-fold, the accuracy is much lower:

```
$ ./svm-train -t 0 -g 2 -c 2 /tmp/tr_pool5_adult01 tmp_model_t0
optimization finished, #iter = 19146
nu = 0.000439
obj = -4.005013, rho = -1.699265
nSV = 2008, nBSV = 2
Total nSV = 2008

$ ./svm-predict /tmp/te_pool5_adult01 tmp_model_t0 /dev/null
Accuracy = 64.8352% (354/546) (classification)
```

The same happens with polynomial kernels:

```
log2c=1 log2g=1 rate=84.3846

$ ./svm-train -v 5 -t 1 -d 2 -g 2 -c 2 /tmp/giraudf/tr_pool5_adult01 /dev/null
[...]
Cross Validation Accuracy = 84.3846%

$ ./svm-train -t 1 -d 2 -g 2 -c 2 /tmp/tr_pool5_adult01 tmp_model_t1d2
[...]
optimization finished, #iter = 457897
nu = 0.000438
obj = -4.000000, rho = -1.013651
nSV = 3119, nBSV = 2
Total nSV = 3119

$ ./svm-predict /tmp/te_pool5_adult01 tmp_model_t1d2 /dev/null                           
Accuracy = 60.6227% (331/546) (classification)
```

The polynomial kernel seems better than the linear one according to the grid search (and the n-fold training), but at the end gives worse performances. How is this possible?

My questions are: why there is so much difference in accuracy between the n-fold version and the normal one? Is it a matter of overfitting? In the [libSVM guide](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/guide/guide.pdf) they first run the grid search, then take the best parameters (C and g), re-train with those parameters and get the same accuracy as in the grid search. This is not happening to me. Am i doing something wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: "but at the end gives worse performances. How is this possible?" - That usually happens due to overfitting...

Comment: Ok that was also what i thought, but to me it seems weird that in their guide this is not happening. And what is the purpose of the grid search if the actual accuracy seems completely uncorrelated?